# Protobuf custom options not showing in JSON made by protojson library

Tags: json, go, protocol-buffers, proto, google-app-engine-golang

I'm trying to **extract Protobuf custom options from a FileDescriptorSet** generated by the protoc compiler. I'm unable to do so using protoreflect. So, I tried to do so using the protojson library.

PS : Importing the Go-generated code is not an option for my use case.

Here's the Protobuf Message I'm testing with :

```
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "./protoze";

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
    string Meta = 50000;
}
extend google.protobuf.FileOptions {
    string Food = 50001;
}
option (Food) = "cheese";
message X {
 int64 num = 1;
}
message P {
    string Fname          = 1 [json_name = "FNAME"];
    string Lname          = 2 [json_name = "0123", (Meta) = "Yo"]; 
    string Designation    = 3;
    repeated string Email = 4;
    string UserID         = 5;
    string EmpID          = 6;
    repeated X z          = 7;
}
// protoc --go_out=. filename.proto
```

Here's how far I got :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os/exec"

    "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/descriptorpb"
)

func main() {
    exec.Command("protoc", "-oBinaryFile", "1.proto").Run()
    Fset := descriptorpb.FileDescriptorSet{}
    byts, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("File")
    proto.Unmarshal(byts, &Fset)
    byts, _ = protojson.Marshal(Fset.File[0])
    fmt.Println(string(byts))
}
```

And here's the output JSON

```
{
  "name": "1.proto",
  "dependency": [
    "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto"
  ],
  "messageType": [
    {
      "name": "X",
      "field": [
        {
          "name": "num",
          "number": 1,
          "label": "LABEL_OPTIONAL",
          "type": "TYPE_INT64",
          "jsonName": "num"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "P",
      "field": [
        {
          "name": "Fname",
          "number": 1,
          "label": "LABEL_OPTIONAL",
          "type": "TYPE_STRING",
          "jsonName": "FNAME"
        },
        {
          "name": "Lname",
          "number": 2,
          "label": "LABEL_OPTIONAL",
          "type": "TYPE_STRING",
          "jsonName": "0123",
          "options": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "Designation",
          "number": 3,
          "label": "LABEL_OPTIONAL",
          "type": "TYPE_STRING",
          "jsonName": "Designation"
        },
        {
          "name": "Email",
          "number": 4,
          "label": "LABEL_REPEATED",
          "type": "TYPE_STRING",
          "jsonName": "Email"
        },
        {
          "name": "UserID",
          "number": 5,
          "label": "LABEL_OPTIONAL",
          "type": "TYPE_STRING",
          "jsonName": "UserID"
        },
        {
          "name": "EmpID",
          "number": 6,
          "label": "LABEL_OPTIONAL",
          "type": "TYPE_STRING",
          "jsonName": "EmpID"
        },
        {
          "name": "z",
          "number": 7,
          "label": "LABEL_REPEATED",
          "type": "TYPE_MESSAGE",
          "typeName": ".X",
          "jsonName": "z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "extension": [
    {
      "name": "Meta",
      "number": 50000,
      "label": "LABEL_OPTIONAL",
      "type": "TYPE_STRING",
      "extendee": ".google.protobuf.FieldOptions",
      "jsonName": "Meta"
    },
    {
      "name": "Food",
      "number": 50001,
      "label": "LABEL_OPTIONAL",
      "type": "TYPE_STRING",
      "extendee": ".google.protobuf.FileOptions",
      "jsonName": "Food"
    }
  ],
  "options": {
    "goPackage": "./protoze"
  },
  "syntax": "proto3"
}
```

So, data about my custom options showed up in the extensions. But what I really wanted was the value of those Custom Options in the "options" as well. (Which in my case was (Food) = "Cheese" and I want Cheese)

**Can someone tell me how I can extract my custom options from the FileDescriptorSet using Protoreflect or by using Protojson.**

I tried a lot to try and extract it using Protoreflect but failed !

Answer (score 1):

Although not specifically an answer to how to get the custom options in a generated JSON, I believe I have an answer to what sounds like your underlying question: how to access the custom options without loading the generated Go code. This is thanks to dsnet's answer to my question on the [golang issues board](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/1260). Needless to say all the credit for this tricky solution goes to him. The punchline is to Marshal and then Unmarshal the options using a runtime-populated protoregistry.Types that actually knows about the custom options.

I made a complete demonstration of this approach working [in this repo](https://github.com/tgorton617/protoc-gen-go-option-example), and the key section (all the guts of which come from dsnet's example) is here:

```golang
func main() {
    protogen.Options{
    }.Run(func(gen *protogen.Plugin) error {

        gen.SupportedFeatures = uint64(pluginpb.CodeGeneratorResponse_FEATURE_PROTO3_OPTIONAL)

        // The type information for all extensions is in the source files,
        // so we need to extract them into a dynamically created protoregistry.Types.
        extTypes := new(protoregistry.Types)
        for _, file := range gen.Files {
            if err := registerAllExtensions(extTypes, file.Desc); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }

        // run through the files again, extracting and printing the Message options
        for _, sourceFile := range gen.Files {
            if !sourceFile.Generate {
                continue
            }

            // setup output file
            outputfile := gen.NewGeneratedFile("./out.txt", sourceFile.GoImportPath)

            for _, message := range sourceFile.Messages {
                outputfile.P(fmt.Sprintf("\nMessage %s:", message.Desc.Name()))

                // The MessageOptions as provided by protoc does not know about
                // dynamically created extensions, so they are left as unknown fields.
                // We round-trip marshal and unmarshal the options with
                // a dynamically created resolver that does know about extensions at runtime.
                options := message.Desc.Options().(*descriptorpb.MessageOptions)
                b, err := proto.Marshal(options)
                if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
                options.Reset()
                err = proto.UnmarshalOptions{Resolver: extTypes}.Unmarshal(b, options)
                if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }

                // Use protobuf reflection to iterate over all the extension fields,
                // looking for the ones that we are interested in.
                options.ProtoReflect().Range(func(fd protoreflect.FieldDescriptor, v protoreflect.Value) bool {
                    if !fd.IsExtension() {
                        return true
                    }

                    outputfile.P(fmt.Sprintf("Value of option %s is %s",fd.Name(), v.String()))

                    // Make use of fd and v based on their reflective properties.

                    return true
                })
            }
        }
        
        return nil
    })
}

// Recursively register all extensions into the provided protoregistry.Types,
// starting with the protoreflect.FileDescriptor and recursing into its MessageDescriptors,
// their nested MessageDescriptors, and so on.
//
// This leverages the fact that both protoreflect.FileDescriptor and protoreflect.MessageDescriptor 
// have identical Messages() and Extensions() functions in order to recurse through a single function
func registerAllExtensions(extTypes *protoregistry.Types, descs interface {
    Messages() protoreflect.MessageDescriptors
    Extensions() protoreflect.ExtensionDescriptors
}) error {
    mds := descs.Messages()
    for i := 0; i < mds.Len(); i++ {
        registerAllExtensions(extTypes, mds.Get(i))
    }
    xds := descs.Extensions()
    for i := 0; i < xds.Len(); i++ {
        if err := extTypes.RegisterExtension(dynamicpb.NewExtensionType(xds.Get(i))); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```